# React-Native Expo Location Getting iOS Permissions

Tags: react-native, expo, location, ios-permissions

I'm developing a react-native app with Expo, and using expo-location for getting a phone's location.
Here are all my dependencies, in case there are conflicts unknown to me:
[Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y15Uy.png)

In the current setup, I'm using a loading screen to request both foreground and background permissions (and some other things, for example establishing a firebase connection and getting push permissions).
After the permissions, a Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync is started, which is what I need these permissions for.

The problems only occur on a real device via Expo Go (device used iPhone 12 mini, iOS 15.3.1).
On an iOS Emulator, real and emulated Android devices, none of these problems occur.

If I try to request both location permissions, the app ends in the loading screen, because Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsny never resolves with the following error:
[Error, when asking for backgroundPermission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjIU2.png)

If I comment the background permission request out, I get the Foreground permission, but I get the following warning:
[Warning, when only asking for foregroundPermissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRpc8.png)

I already included both UIBackgroundModes and UsageDescription in my json.
[app json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0p6j.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can try `requestforegroundpermissionsasync`

- Asks the user to grant permissions for location while the app is in the foreground.

Example

```js
 let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }
```

Comment: My Task needs to work while the app is in the background as well. I want to send possible Push Notifactions, if the user reaches a location.

Comment: It indeed does request locations permissions but even after allowing, it still shows that the location permissions are not granted